# "Cannot navigate to definition" annoyance in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just switched to Visual Studio 2010, and now whenever I select something, Ctrl+C to copy, click somewhere else, and Ctrl+V to paste, I get an error message "Cannot navigate to definition." After that, it I try it again, it works. What fantastic new 'feature' should I be turning off to stop this?

[image]

Comment: Didn't you hear? That was by design ;)

Comment: Tools + Import/Export, Reset sounds appropriate here.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Bah, it's a bug in Microsoft Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2010. the "Ctrl+Click Go To Definition" feature. Apparently, when I click a new location and then press "Ctrl+V" - if I do it quickly enough, it interprets it as a Ctrl+Click and immediately tries to trigger a navigation, even if I clicked on an empty space. The error comes because it doesn't know what I'm trying to navigate to (answer: I'm not).

Comment: Thank you for posting this! It's been driving me CRAZY.

Comment: Have you found a way to continue working in Visual Studio without restarting the application?

Comment: @conroyrw When I get the annoying popups I just do a ctrl+click somewhere in the file, then close the next popup/alert then it goes away, it's as if it thinks the ctrl button is stuck down!

Comment: @Treborbob Thanks for the tip.  Of course, now that I have an solution, it hasn't happened in awhile.

Comment: @conroyrw  Seems to happen to me every time I stop debugging and immediately try editing code (especially after being annoyed once more at the box that pops up telling me I can't edit while debugging!)

Comment: I just disabled the Ctrl+Click feature in Power Tools and haven't seen the error since.

Comment: This is still an issue in the 2012 version as well.

Comment: Tools => Options => Productivity Power Tools => Turn Off Ctrl+Click Go To Definition

Comment: Is it possible only to disable the control v? The Control Click to definition is great..

Comment: Instead of completely disabling the feature (I really like Ctrl+Click) is it not possible to just **turn off the dialog box?** I wouldn't care whether it turned off just for Ctrl+Click or for any Go To Definition, but I really feel that the dialog box should have one of those "Do not show again" checkboxes...

Comment: @CarlWalsh I whole heartedly agree, I'll go thumb through the options.

Answer (score 2):

I have/had similar issues in VS 2012 (Premium).

I've tried the following:

- removed all bin and obj folders from project's folder: works most of
     the time.
- repaired VS 2012 (add/remove bugrams (programs) > repair). Didn't
  help much.
- Close and opened VS 2012: didn’t help much either.
- I've noticed than I couldn't open only files that weren't check-in in
  TFS. I check-in them and then VS started working    normally.

Dunno if this issue will appear again tough.

Hopefully this would help someone.

BR

Comment: I think there is some issue with Team Foundation Server. If I check in code it starts working.

Comment: "Close and opened VS 2012" it helped me to go to defn which is in an external file

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the GoToDefProPack.dll file from the following location:
C:\Users(myUserName)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions\Microsoft\Productivity Power Tools\10.0.20318.14
to disable this feature completely.